# Where do I change the string "Subscription to CiviCRM..." for Stripe payment processor

Tags: stripe

I hesitated to post this as I think the field should be easily findable, but alas I've given up.

I have donation pages set up using stripe (with recurring payments).
The recurring subscription works, but the description is:
"Subscription to CiviCRM every 1 months $50.00"

Where can I change this description passed to Stripe?

Comment: Hi - where do you see that wording?

Comment: I too would like to know the answer to this.
The "Subscription to CiviCRM every..." appears on the Stripe generated receipts and as the description of the subscription details in the dashboard too

Comment: According to comment by Scott, *The "Subscription to CiviCRM every..." appears on the Stripe generated receipts and as the description of the subscription details in the dashboard too.*

Answer (score 1):

The Answer - turn on Stripe receipts, and turn on civiCRM receipts. The item itself cannot be changed (at least that was the answer I found when I explored a long time ago).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this answer? Has anyone found a solution here?